# Unable to call output of my cursor for use in output

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have an Oracle Apex page where I receive 4 variables from the page.

```
:P1_COL1
:P1_COL2
:P1_COL3
:P1_COL4
```

The problem here is that P1_COL4 can receive many values and they are separated by a  colon. So what I did was that I declared a cursor with a regexp to delimit the rows by a  colon.

For example,

Currently this is what the output is if I do:

```
select :P1_COL1,:P1_COL2,:P1_COL3,:P1_COL4 from dual;
```

> BOB,JONES,M,BLUE:RED:GREEN:YELLOW:PURPLE

Whereas I'm looking for something like this...

```
Bob, Jones, M, BLUE
Bob, Jones, M, RED
Bob, Jones, M, GREEN
Bob, Jones, M, YELLOW
Bob, Jones, M, PURPLE
```

But currently my code is not working

```
DECLARE CURSOR a1
is
        WITH statement AS
    (
        select :P1_COL4 obj
        from dual
    )
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(OBJ,'[^,:;]+',1,LEVEL) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(OBJ,'[^,:;]+'))+1;

begin
for x in a1
loop
dbms_output.put_line(:P1_COL1 ||','|| :P1_Col2 ||','||
     :P1_Col3||','|| a1 || chr(13));
 end loop;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the colon  delimited string separately and use cross join to include other columns.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/779)

```
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT 'Bob'                          AS P1_COL1, 
                'Jones'                        AS P1_COL2, 
                'M'                            AS P1_COL3, 
                'BLUE:RED:GREEN:YELLOW:PURPLE' AS P1_COL4 
         FROM   dual) 
SELECT d.p1_col1, 
       d.p1_col2, 
       d.p1_col3, 
       s.col 
FROM   data d 
       cross join (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(p1_col4, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS col 
                     FROM   data 
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(p1_col4, '[^:]+')) s
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/779/0)**:

```
| P1_COL1 | P1_COL2 | P1_COL3 |    COL |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|
|     Bob |   Jones |       M |   BLUE |
|     Bob |   Jones |       M |    RED |
|     Bob |   Jones |       M |  GREEN |
|     Bob |   Jones |       M | YELLOW |
|     Bob |   Jones |       M | PURPLE |
```

You could also simplify your query without a with clause and selecting those variables directly from dual.

**EDIT**

> I'm trying to use `for loop`

This is how you could do it.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
  FOR r IN
  (
   SELECT :p1_col1 as p1_col1
     ,:p1_col2 as p1_col2
     ,:p1_col3 as p1_col3
     ,s.p1_col4
FROM dual d
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:p1_col4, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS p1_col4
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(:p1_col4, '[^:]+')
    ) s )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (r.p1_col1
    ||','
    || r.p1_col2
    ||','
    || r.p1_col3
    || r.p1_col4
    || CHR(13));
  END LOOP; 
 END;
 /
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However that does work via SQL. I'm trying to use p1_col4 outside of a for loop so I can print the results like this.  dbms_output.put_line (:P1_COL1 ||','|| :P1_COL2 ||','||
         :P1_COL3 || p1_col4 || chr(13));   Basically I'm trying to use the code in a loop such as for x in (query) print out the results

Comment: @TonySawah : Please check edits.

Comment: Thank you so much All. been a great help. Kaushik, that is gold.